# Plane that is constructed by vectors

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis, vectors

I found the following in my notes:

The plane that is constructed by two non-parallel vectors $\overrightarrow{v}$ and  $\overrightarrow{w}$ consists of all the points of the form $a \overrightarrow{v}+b\overrightarrow{w}$, $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$.

The plane that is defined by $\overrightarrow{v}$ and $\overrightarrow{w}$ is called the plane that is produced by $\overrightarrow{v}$ and $\overrightarrow{w}$.

If $\overrightarrow{v}$ is a multiple of $\overrightarrow{w}$ and $\overrightarrow{w} \neq 0$, then $\overrightarrow{v}$ and $\overrightarrow{w}$ are parallel.

I am asked to find the plane that is produced by the two vectors $\overrightarrow{v_1}=(3, 8, 0)$ and $\overrightarrow{v_2}=(0, 3, 8)$.

Is the plane $a \overrightarrow{v_1}+b\overrightarrow{v_2}$ ?? Or is this only the form of points of the plane??

Comment: $r=a\vec{x}+b\vec{y}$ for $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ describes all points which are linear combinations of the two vectors. This is an explicit description of the plane. Pick values for a and b then you have a point in 3D space and all such choices lie on the same plane. You can also have an implicit equation for a plane e.g 3x - 2y + 4z = 2 is a plane. In this case, choices of y and z will fix the value of x giving a point in 3D. All possible choices of y and z will result in a plane of points.

Comment: I see... Thank you so much!!! :-) @Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several common descriptions of a 3D plane:
$$
a_1 v_1 + a_2 v_2 \quad (a_1, a_2 \in \mathbb{R})
$$
The above one is the one you assumed in your question.

Another way to model all vectors $x$ of a 3D plane is by a normal vector $n$:
$$
0 = x \cdot n = a_1 (v_1 \cdot n) + a_2 (v_2 \cdot n)
$$
so $n$ should fulfill these two conditions:
\begin{align}
0 &= (3,8,0) \cdot (n_1, n_2, n_3) = 3 n_1 + 8 n_2 \wedge \\
0 &= (0,3,8) \cdot (n_1, n_2, n_3) = 3 n_2 + 8 n_3 
\end{align}

You might guess the normal vector or use the vector product to derive one:
$$
n = v_1 \times v_2 
= (8\cdot 8 - 0\cdot 3, 0\cdot 0 - 3\cdot 8, 3 \cdot 3 - 8 \cdot 0)
= (64, -24, 9)
$$

Comment: I understand... Thank you very much!!! :-)